# CakePHP: Redirecting users away from / if they are authenticated

Tags: cakephp, authentication

On CakePHP 2.2 using AuthComponent, what is the best way to redirect a user from '/' to '/users' if they are already authenticated?  All of my searches have just turned up information about the AuthComponent's loginRedirect and related.  I read a post detailing changing the Routes (in 1.x), but I wasn't sure if this was still the best way.  I could also insert

```
if($path[0] == 'home' && $this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
    $this->redirect('/users/');
}
```

in PageController::display(), but again, not sure if this is the most desirable method

The index page for this application will simply be a page asking the user to sign up or log in, so it is of little importance to members already logged in.

Edit:
After revisiting the beforeFilter() method, I came up with

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('*');

    if($this->request->params['pass'][0] == 'home' && $this->Session->check('Auth.User'))
        $this->redirect('/users');
}
```

but this seems really static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way is to redirect user from the controller's beforeFilter method. Redirecting from .ctp file is not good.

// In PagesController.cpp

```
beforeFilter() {
  if($path[0] == 'home' && $this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
      $this->redirect('/users/');
  }
}
```

Some sort of similar:
[CakePHP Auth component redirect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636274/cakephp-auth-component-redirect-issue/2636940#2636940)

Comment: I revised the title to eliminate confusion; With home.ctp I was simply implying the root url - the redirect wasn't actually in the ctp file.

Your method urged me to revisit the beforeFilter, using Session::check instead of checking Auth->user, which works.  The working code is pasted above in my original post.

Comment: Don't forget to call parent controller's beforeFilter function, inside derived function.